# command window is blanked?

Tags: texstudio

In latex (TeX studio),my command window is not working,i can't edit any thing on it...its completely blanked,but my PDF is displayed. log file hundred error messages are  **1.Text line contains an invalid character???** 
second only message is
**Process started: pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "working document".tex**

> Process exited with error(s)

i can't post my code because my command window is blanked. 
i have tried to change settings but its not work?
thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Sorry but without more details it will be really hard to help you because you have not given us enough information to see what the problem is. Ideally we need a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). What happens if you try and compile the document directly from the command line? What about if you (save and) restart TeX studio?

Comment: if i open any other file in command window its work,,, but that specifical file not worked,it show blank window even after restart...

Comment: I'm not understanding what you mean by TeX studio's "command window".  Are you talking about where you edit the .tex file?  Or where you see the logged messages?  Or someplace where you can enter specific commands to compile the .tex file?